# Grails 2.5.0 - data cannot be created and linked to another object in a service

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The following code is throwing an error in a Grails service:

```
def mydata = new MyData([data: data]).save()
user1.addToData(mydata).save()
user2.addToSecondData(mydata).save()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NULL not allowed for column "MYDATA_ID"
```

This code works fine in a controller if I flush the save on the first line. I want this in a service so that it's saved transactionally, though. How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

Below are the essentials of the two classes:

```
class User { 
... 
static hasMany = [data: MyData, secondData: MyData] 
... 
}

class MyData { 
... 
static belongsTo = User
static hasMany = [for: User]
...
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've found a workaround, although it's very hackish, and a more elegant solution would be much better. I don't know why it works, but changing the User hasMany to `static hasMany = [data: MyData, secondData: MyData, dummyData: MyData]` fixes the problem.

Comment: post the essentials of your mydata and user domain clases

Comment: added the essentials

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, you are facing the GORM gotcha with several `hasMany` of the same type. By default GORM cannot resolve them and needs to be pushed in the right direction.

See [ref-doc on mappedBy](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany) for details:

So, in your case you have to add

```
class User { 
  ... 
  static hasMany = [data: MyData, secondData: MyData] 
  static mappedBy = [ data:'data', secondData:'secondData' ]
  ... 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on startup: Error loading plugin manager: Non-existent mapping property [secondData]

Comment: If I were you, I'd change the relation structure: bi-directional many-to-many brings way more problems than solutions. Out of my experience, in 90% of cases a simple uni-directional one-to-one is enough, the rest you can implement as queries. In your case, I'd remove `hasMany`s from User class, and leave only `static belongsTo = User` in MyData